# RegularExpression DataAnnotation to validate string EndsWith particular domain name

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I'm using a RegularExpression DataAnnotation attribute to validate the supplied email address conforms to my domain name

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
[RegularExpression(@"@mydomain.co.uk$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a @mydomain.co.uk email address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

However, when this validates, even if I use a @mydomain.co.uk domain, it still displays the error message?

I've tested the regex with regexpal, and it matches - so not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: escape the dots. Put `.*` before `@`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - please submit that as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like i said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638681/regularexpression-dataannotation-to-validate-string-endswith-particular-domain-n/27665612#comment43696179_27638681), you need to escape the dots present in your regex and also you need to add `.*` before `@`.

```
[RegularExpression(@".*@mydomain\.co\.uk$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a @mydomain.co.uk email address")]
```